# Magento 1 Redirect Product to the category page if product doesn't exist or found 404

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am working on Magento 1.9.1. I we have few already deleted products. Currently if we open  that by URL we are getting 404. But I want to redirect these all in their parent category. Is there any event by we can handle 404 ? Any way by we can redirect to category page if product not found ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I think for now is to create a custom 404.html (name as you want) page containing blocks and sections of categories you want (layout).

Then, you edit your .htaccess adding the code:

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

Make sure the .htaccess is saved on the root directory.

From this, every time your website runs a 404 error, the routine will call the 404.html page (or the page you want to call associated to your root website folder)

Hope that helps